# SQL Select rows from 1st table and Update into 2nd Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I have two tables, `tblCity` and `tblCountry` and there's no relationship between them at the moment. I need to add `CountryId`s from `tblCountry` into `tblCity`.

This is `tblCity`:

[image: tblCity]

This is `tblCountry`:

[image: tblCountry]

I need to UPDATE `tblCity.CountryId` (which is `NULL` at the moment) with corresponding `tblCountry.CountryId`

I have `ISO2` and `ISO3` country codes in both tables, so please help me with select and update queries for SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement will match on both ISO2 and ISO3 columns to do the update:

```
UPDATE
    ci
SET
    ci.CountryId = co.CountryId
FROM
    tblCity ci
JOIN
    tblCountry co
    ON
    ci.ISO2 = co.CountryISO2
    AND
    ci.ISO3 = co.CountryISO3
WHERE
    ci.CountryId IS NULL
```

Comment: And let's avoid updates that are not necessary by adding:

    "and ci.CountryId is null;"

It may not be needed now but these sorts of things are often repeated over time.

Comment: @SMor: That's a good suggestion, I'll incorporate it if you don't mind.